# Inner shadow of a polygon in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, kotlin

Is it possible to draw inner shadow for some polygon to make it look like this?
[image]

Comment: Well, the image above got created somehow, so clearly it's not an impossible task. What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck? What's the context you're using this effect in? Do you have your polygons in advance or are they generated at runtime?

Comment: Well, I draw polygons on a Pixmap using EarClippingTriangulator. I thought it could be done by drawing one dark polygon and its blurred copy with target color (e.g. purple like on image), but I don't know how to blur in libgdx...